# What is a correct name for an operation that turns 3-column long table into a compact "2D" table with variable number of columns?

Tags: database, csv, data-manipulation, transformation

For example, from this table

| row | col | val |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A | 32 |
| 0 | B | 31 |
| 0 | C | 35 |
| 1 | A | 30 |
| 1 | B | 29 |
| 1 | C | 29 |
| 2 | A | 15 |
| 2 | B | 14 |
| 2 | D | 18 |
| 3 | A | 34 |
| 3 | B | 39 |
| 3 | C | 34 |
| 3 | D | 35 |

it should produce this table:

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 32 | 31 | 35 |  |
| 1 | 30 | 29 | 29 |  |
| 2 | 15 | 14 |  | 18 |
| 3 | 34 | 39 | 34 | 35 |

Is there some official, canonical (or at least popular specific unambiguous) term for such operation (or its reverse)?

I am trying to find (or implement & publish) a tool that transforms CSV this way, but am unsure what to search for (or how to name it).

Comment: Maybe there is some way to find out names of data transformations in general? E.g. I provide a sample like `(1,2,3,...), 10 -> (1,10,2,10,3,10,...)` and it says "intersperse". Like [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), but for data transformations?

Comment: What database/technology are you looking to accomplish this task in? In many systems this is called a pivot operation.

Comment: The term is [pivot](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

Comment: @HenryEcker Primarily in CLI processing of CSV files (tools like `xsv`, `csvtool`, `q-text-as-data`). "Pivot" seems to be the term I looked for - I found "Google Sheets" has such operation, also there is a [CLI tool](https://lib.rs/crates/clipivot) for it already - hard to find it if you don't know about the "pivot" term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term is [*pivot*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table).

Some databases have native support for pivot, eg SQL Server's [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-ver16) (and even `UNPIVOT`) keywords.

For most databases you must craft a query that does the job.